# One finger zoom mapbox with angular 5

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

I am trying to do zoom in or zoom out on mapbox with angular 5
I want to tap twice and hold finger on the mapbox and then pan up to zoom in, or down to zoom out
but one finger zoom doesn't work on mapbox

I want to output look like this:

Please help me.

[image]